# Why is the pushType missing from Android parse installation?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, parse-server

I am trying to set up push notifications on Android using GCM and Parse Server. I added the key to server.js, so I am able to send the notifications from the dashboard, however, none are being received by Android. I am able to add the device to the Installation table using `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();`, but, the GCMSenderId, deviceToken, and pushType are all undefined.

After some searching, I thought maybe it was a problem with my manifest. I added these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Then, inside the `<application>`, I added `<meta-data android:name="com.pickmeup.push.gcm_sender_id" android:value="id:NUMBER_FROM_GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_CONSOLE" />`. Then before I closed the `<application>`, I added:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.myAppPackage" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:NUMBER_FROM_GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_CONSOLE" />
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you make sure all of your package names match up. I had this problem before, and it was because of that. 
Also, parse is deprecating starting next year. Just as a reminder/heads-up...

Comment: The package names should all be correct. At least Android Studio was able to find all the packages. And they are stopping parse.com, but I am using a self-hosted open-source parse-server, so it shouldn't be an issue, although it is frustrating how much of the docs and tutorials are still for parse.com.